# Nth power of a matrix

Tags: matrices, power-series, markov-chains

I have a transition matrix $P$ (hence it's rows add up to 1) and I would like to compute it's Nth power. I am finding a lot of answers using the 'Diagonalization' method however I want to prove that actually the Nth power can be written as

$P^N=\sum\limits_{j=1}^kC_j \psi_j^N$ where $C_j$ are constant matrices computed from $P$ and its eigenvalues and $\psi_1,\ldots,\psi_k$ are distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: $k$ is the size of the transition matrix $P$. This statement is found in a paper and it considers the case when all eigenvalues are distinct.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the paper?

Comment: [Haas](https://academic.oup.com/jfec/article/2/4/493/900480) et al. page 525 equation 50

Comment: It’s worth noting that $C_j$ is a projection onto the eigenspace of $\psi_j$ and that if $j\ne k$, $C_jC_k=C_kC_j=0$. There’s a way to compute these projections without computing any eigenvectors.

Comment: @amd can you kindly elaborate how these projections are worked out?

Comment: Brief sketch: $P-\psi_kI$ annihilates the eigenspace of $\psi_k$, so the image of $\prod_{k\ne j}(P-\psi_kI)$ is the eigenspace of $\psi_j$. This needs to be divided by an easily-computed normalization factor to ensure that it’s the identity map on the eigenspace of $\psi_j$, which gives you the required projection. This construction is mainly of theoretical interest for any but fairly small matrices $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P$ has distinct eigenvalues, then it is diagonalizable.
Any diagonalizable matrix can be expressed in that form:

Let 
$$
A = M D M^{-1}
$$ 
a diagonalizable matrix with $D$ diagonal. Then you can write
$$
D = \sum_i \psi_i e_ie_i^T
$$
where $\psi_i$ are the eigenvalues. Then
$$
A = \sum_i \psi_i Me_ie_i^TM^{-1}
$$
and
$$
A^N = MD^NM^{-1}= \sum_i \psi_i^N Me_ie_i^TM^{-1}
$$

Comment: Thank-you very much!! To be sure, M is the matrix with the eigenvectors of A right?

Comment: @Anna Yes. It’s a change-of-basis matrix that diagonalizes $A$.